# Webpack 3.3 & NodeJs 8.1 Cross-file inheritance gives TypeError?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, webpack

So I'm having a strange error with Webpack 3.3 and NodeJS 8.10 (running on AWS Lambda). The error message is:

```
module initialization error: TypeError
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:6480:55)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:6134:21)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:6287:24)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:20:30)
at DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:63:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/presenters/api/financial/posts.js:66:10)
... truncated
```

Line 6480 of the webpack file is:

```
const FinancialEvent = __webpack_require__(59);
// Other requires removed for clarity.
const {
  financial: {
    environments
  }
} = __webpack_require__(14);class DwollaEvent extends FinancialEvent {
```

Over in the parent class file FinancialEvent.js, there's:

```
class FinancialEvent extends Object {
 // Truncated for clarity.
}
module.exports = FinancialEvent;
```

If I eliminate this cross-file inheritance, the error goes away:

```
const FinancialEvent = __webpack_require__(59);
// Other requires removed for clarity.
const {
  financial: {
    environments
  }
} = __webpack_require__(14);
class DummyParent extends Object {
}

class DwollaEvent extends DummyParent {
```

The error also stops if I copy the FinancialEvent class into DwollaEvent.js and refer to it directly.

Is this a known issue with Webpack & cross-file inheritance in NodeJS? Does anyone have a solution? Just so you know, upgrading to Webpack 4.0 isn't a solution for the moment, because of the significant changes that were made to the configuration files, etc. Upgrading NodeJS isn't a solution because that's what AWS Lambda supports.

Thanks in advance!